# Separate Comma Delimited Cells To New Rows

Tags: r

Hi I have a table with comma delimited columns and I need to convert the comma delimited values to new rows. for exmaple the given table is

```
Name     Start      End 
A        1,2,3    4,5,6
B          1,2      4,5
C      1,2,3,4  6,7,8,9
```

I need to convert it like

```
Name Start End
   A     1   4
   A     2   5  
   A     3   6
   B     1   4
   B     2   5 
   C     1   6
   C     2   7
   C     3   8   
   C     4   9
```

I can do that using VB script but I need to solve it using R
Can anyone solve this?

Comment: This question belongs on an R language server, not here.

Comment: read the file with read.csv and write with write.table, convert to appropriate format with melt. This question is similar to your most recent questions, it really does not belong here. Please ask in stackoverflow.

Comment: Oh ok. I'm new to R thought CV is an R community. Will follow it next time :)

Comment: welcome to the site! With regard to CV vs SO, there is some overlap in terms of active members on each site and the types of questions that are appropriate on each site. See [this post](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/584/vote-on-policy-for-r-questions) for some of that discussion. CV is certainly an R community (highest tag on the site) but the questions are generally more grounded in statistical questions or an R implementation of those questions. SO deals more with the programming with R side of the equation...though it's certainly shades of gray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach that should work for you. I'm assuming that your three input vectors are in different objects. We are going to create a list of those inputs and write a function that process each object and returns them in the form of a `data.frame` with plyr.

The things to take note of here are the splitting of the character vector into it's component parts, then using `as.numeric` to convert the numbers from the character form when they were split. Since R fills matrices by column, we define a 2 column matrix and let R fill the values for us. We then retrieve the Name column and put it all together in a `data.frame`. `plyr` is nice enough to process the list and convert it into a `data.frame` for us automatically.

```
library(plyr)

a <- paste("A",1, 2,3,4,5,6, sep = ",", collapse = "")
b <- paste("B",1, 2,4,5, sep = ",", collapse = "")
c <- paste("C",1, 2,3,4,6,7,8,9, sep = ",", collapse = "")

input <- list(a,b,c)

splitter <- function(x) {
    x <- unlist(strsplit(x, ","))
    out <- data.frame(x[1], matrix(as.numeric(x[-1]), ncol = 2))
    colnames(out) <- c("Name", "Start", "End")
    return(out)
}


ldply(input, splitter)
```

And the output:

```
> ldply(input, splitter)
 Name Start End
1    A     1   4
2    A     2   5
3    A     3   6
4    B     1   4
5    B     2   5
6    C     1   6
7    C     2   7
8    C     3   8
9    C     4   9
```

Answer (score 3):

You might have asked this question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) as there is no issue dealing with statistics :)

Anyway, I made up a quite complicated and ugly solution which might work for you:

```
# load your data
x <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C"), Start = c("1,2,3", "1,2", 
"1,2,3,4"), End = c("4,5,6", "4,5", "6,7,8,9")), .Names = c("Name", 
"Start", "End"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Which looks like in R like:

```
> x
  Name   Start     End length
1    A   1,2,3   4,5,6      3
2    B     1,2     4,5      2
3    C 1,2,3,4 6,7,8,9      4
```

Data transformation with the help of `strsplit` calls:

```
data <- data.frame(cbind(
    rep(x$Name,as.numeric(lapply(strsplit(x$Start,","), length))),
    unlist(lapply(strsplit(x$Start,","), cbind)),
    unlist(lapply(strsplit(x$End,","), cbind))
    ))
```

Naming the new data frame:

```
names(data) <- c("Name", "Start", "End")
```

Which looks like:

```
> data
  Name Start End
1    A     1   4
2    A     2   5
3    A     3   6
4    B     1   4
5    B     2   5
6    C     1   6
7    C     2   7
8    C     3   8
9    C     4   9
```

Comment: "I made up a quite complicated and ugly solution which might work for you"  Thanks for making me smile. ;-)

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich: I am happy that my answer had a nice effect :)

Answer (score 2):

The `separate_rows()` function in `tidyr` is the boss for observations with multiple delimited values...

```
# create data 
library(tidyverse)
d <- data_frame(
  Name = c("A", "B", "C"), 
  Start = c("1,2,3", "1,2", "1,2,3,4"), 
  End = c("4,5,6", "4,5", "6,7,8,9")
)
d
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#    Name   Start     End
#   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>
# 1     A   1,2,3   4,5,6
# 2     B     1,2     4,5
# 3     C 1,2,3,4 6,7,8,9

# tidy data
separate_rows(d, Start, End)
# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#    Name Start   End
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1     A     1     4
# 2     A     2     5
# 3     A     3     6
# 4     B     1     4
# 5     B     2     5
# 6     C     1     6
# 7     C     2     7
# 8     C     3     8
# 9     C     4     9

# use convert set to TRUE for integer column modes
separate_rows(d, Start, End, convert = TRUE)
# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#    Name Start   End
#   <chr> <int> <int>
# 1     A     1     4
# 2     A     2     5
# 3     A     3     6
# 4     B     1     4
# 5     B     2     5
# 6     C     1     6
# 7     C     2     7
# 8     C     3     8
# 9     C     4     9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another, just for fun. Take `d` as the original data.

```
f <- function(x, ul = TRUE)
{
    x <- deparse(substitute(x))
    if(ul) unlist(strsplit(d[[x]], ','))
    else strsplit(d[[x]], ',')
}

> data.frame(Name = rep(d$Name, sapply(f(End, F), length)),
             Start = f(Start), End = f(End))
#   Name Start End
# 1    A     1   4
# 2    A     2   5
# 3    A     3   6
# 4    B     1   4
# 5    B     2   5
# 6    C     1   6
# 7    C     2   7
# 8    C     3   8
# 9    C     4   9
```